# La función mysql_num_rows me indica que he pasado valores que sólo son booleanos en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo un script en *PHP* que realiza varios insert a una base de datos en *MySQL*, pero al introducir los datos me dice lo siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practicas/01ejercico.php on line 62

```
<?php
//declaramos las variable introducida en el formulario
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$iva = $_POST['iva'];
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$idcliente = $_POST['idcliente'];
//abrimos la conexión al servidor mysql
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ras", "ras")
or die("No es posible conectarse a la BD");
//seleccionamos la base de datos
mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "ZAPATOS")
or die ("no se puede seleccionar la BD" );
//Declaramos las condiciones de inserción:
echo "<h3>El formato de la fecha es AAAA/MM/DD </br>";
if (isset($estado) && isset($fecha) && isset($codigo) && isset($iva) && isset($subtotal) && isset($total) && isset($usuario) && isset($idcliente))
{
    //definimos las consultas
    //PARA QUE NO DE ERRORES LA PK AÑADIMOS EL ID DE CLIENTE
    $consultaclient = "INSERT INTO `CLIENTE` (`idcliente`, `nomcliente`, `email`, `empresa`, `pais`, `ciudad`, `clave`) VALUES ('$idcliente', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', '0')"
    or die("(1) No se ha podido ejecutar esta consulta porque esa idcliente ya existe");
    $introdu1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaclient);
    $consultaprod = "INSERT INTO `PEDIDO` (`idpedido`, `idcliente`, `fecha`, `subtotal`, `iva`, `total`, `estado`, `usuario`) VALUES ('$codigo','$idcliente','$fecha','$subtotal','$iva','$total','$estado','$usuario')"
    or die("No se ha podido ejecutar esta consulta");
    $introdu2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaprod);
    $resultado = mysqli_result(result, row)
    $numfilas = mysqli_num_rows ($introdu2);
    if ($numfilas > 0)
    {
        print ("<TABLE border>\n");
        print ("<TR>\n");
        print ("<td>Idpedido</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Idcliente</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Fecha</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Subtotal</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Iva</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Total</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Estado</td>\n");
        print ("<td>Usuario</td>\n");
        print ("</TR>\n");
        for ($i=0; $i<$numfilas; $i++){
            $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array ($consultaprod);
            print ("<TR>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['idpedido'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['idcliente'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['fecha'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['subtotal'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['iva'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['total'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['estado'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("<TD>" . $resultado['usuario'] . "</TD>\n");
            print ("</TR>\n");
            print ("</TABLE>\n");
            }
    }
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en tu código en `mysqli_result()`, no sé muy bien que es lo que estás haciendo en dicho línea, si la eliminas, te habrá solucionado muy probable el problema.

Tu Código:

```
$resultado = mysqli_result(result, row)
```

Debería quedar:

```
$introdu2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaprod);     
$numfilas = mysqli_num_rows ($introdu2);
if ($numfilas > 0) {
}
```

Aunque te va seguir lanzando el mismo error `mysqli_num_rows`, porque estas insertando datos y no estas seleccionado ningún dato desde tu Base de datos.

> También deberías tener en cuenta de escapar los caracteres que obtienes desde el formulario, **mysqli_real_escape_string**, por motivos de seguridad.

```
$estado = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['estado'];
```

Comment: Efectivamente, la línea no me servía, editaré con el cófigo completo cuando pueda

Comment: Perfecto @ras212, que tengas suerte.

Comment: @ras212, de todas formas debes revisar más el código, ya que tu sentencia es de `INSERT` datos a tu Base de datos y no la estas seleccionado mediante `SELECT`, asique te va insertar correctamente los datos, y después te va seguir lanzando el error de Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 . Deberías crear otra sentencia para mostrar dichos datos después del if ($numfilas), ya que no estas seleccionado ningún registro, en caso que sean los mismos datos que se completó en el formulario, lo podrías mostrar directamente con $_POST. y te evitas dicha sentencia.

Answer (score 2):

La funcion que debes usar es [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

> **mysqli_affected_rows**: Devuelve el numero de filas afectadas por la última consulta INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE.
>
> Nota: Para instrucciones SELECT **mysqli_affected_rows()** es equivalente a [mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)